# How can I set bottom insets globally for a bigger tabbar?

Tags: uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an app that requires a bigger tabbar (height = 75), but when I change the height of the tabbar then the Safe Area insets don't change, so when I make constraints to the bottom margin, it does not work and my content is covered by my tabbar. Also, `UITableView`s don't set the correct insets, so they can't scroll to the bottom.

I set the height of my tabbar by adding this overrided func in my `UITabBarController` subclass:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    var tabbarHeight: CGFloat = 75

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            tabbarHeight += window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        }
    }

    var tabFrame = tabBar.frame
    tabFrame.size.height = tabbarHeight
    tabFrame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - tabbarHeight;
    tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
}
```

Is this the right way to do this? Is there a better way to do this?